# In what scenario we use Linked List implementation for Stack

Tags: python, data-structures, stack

In python a Stack implementation can be created using list. However, what are the benefits of creating stacks using Linked List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter that much in Python, since it can expand the list capacity when needed in constant time. A linked list implementation allows for the stack to dynamically change size without redefining the structure. So in this case, the benefits are pretty minimal, but it would be more important in other languages where an array would have to be reallocated to change size.